# How to prevent running i=j in double for loops in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to prevent running the `i=j` case and substitute it as `NA` in `R`. Here I prepared a small example. When `i=j`, I have the output `0`. But I want to print it as `NA`. How can I do this one? Thanks.

```
n = 5
for(j in 1:(n-1)){
  for(i in 0:(n-2)){
    print(2^(abs(i-j)))
  }
}
```

The outputs are `2, 1, 2, 4,...`.

Answer (score 1):

Either `if (i==j) { print(NA) } else { ... }` or `if (i==j) {print(NA); break}`

Comment: Thanks. How do I skip `i=j` and `i>j` case from printing?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `if` statement?

```
n = 5
for(j in 1:(n-1)){
  for(i in 0:(n-2)){
    if(i == j){
      print(NA)
    } else{
      print(2^(abs(i-j)))
      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun here is a vectorized version that might be much more efficient, depending on the size of `n`. It returns a vector, which you could print line by line if that is your desired output.
The idea is to generate the pairings from the nested loop using `expand.grid`, then subtracting these vectors from each other and setting the cases where i==j (i.e. the difference being 0) to NA.

```r
2^abs({
    rd <- do.call(`-`, asplit(expand.grid(j=0:(n-2), i=1:(n-1)), 2))
    rd[rd==0] <- NA; rd})
```

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering how to skip `i=j` and `i>j` case from printing?

Comment: when `i >= j`  then `i - j >=0` so just replace `rd[rd==0] <- NA` with `rd[rd>=0] <- NA` or, if you don't want to print them at all and not return `NA` you could simply return  `rd[rd<0]`. You might want to use a named vector if you want to keep track of the combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ifelse` or `if ... else ...`. Below is one option with `ifelse`:

```
n <- 5
for (j in 1:(n - 1)) {
  for (i in 0:(n - 2)) {
    print(ifelse(i == j, NA, 2^(abs(i - j))))
  }
}
```

giving

```
[1] 2
[1] NA
[1] 2
[1] 4
[1] 4
[1] 2
[1] NA
[1] 2
[1] 8
[1] 4
[1] 2
[1] NA
[1] 16
[1] 8
[1] 4
[1] 2
```

---

Another option is using `NA^(i==j)` as a mask, e.g.,

```
n <- 5
for (j in 1:(n - 1)) {
  for (i in 0:(n - 2)) {
    print(2^(abs(i - j)) * NA^(i == j))
  }
}
```